# Get date from list with `numpy.datetime64`-objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, type-conversion

I have a list with quite some dates. Unfortunately they are all appear as `numpy.datetime64`-object. Does anyone has an idea of how I could extract the actual date?
The list looks like this:

```
[numpy.datetime64('2016-01-04T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2016-01-14T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2016-01-17T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2016-01-24T00:00:00.000000000'),
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by actual date?  A string?  a `datetime` object?

Comment: I meant a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do using `.astype`:

```
dates = [str(x.astype('datetime64[D]')) for x in dates_list]

['2016-01-04', '2016-01-14', '2016-01-17', '2016-01-24']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [570]: alist=[numpy.datetime64('2016-01-04T00:00:00.000000000'), 
     ...:  numpy.datetime64('2016-01-14T00:00:00.000000000'), 
     ...:  numpy.datetime64('2016-01-17T00:00:00.000000000'), 
     ...:  numpy.datetime64('2016-01-24T00:00:00.000000000')]
```

The list converted into a numpy array:

```
In [571]: np.hstack(alist)                                                                                
Out[571]: 
array(['2016-01-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-01-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2016-01-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2016-01-24T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

date only `dtype`:

```
In [572]: np.hstack(alist).astype('datetime64[D]')                                                        
Out[572]: 
array(['2016-01-04', '2016-01-14', '2016-01-17', '2016-01-24'],
      dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

print string of the whole array:

```
In [573]: str(np.hstack(alist).astype('datetime64[D]'))                                                   
Out[573]: "['2016-01-04' '2016-01-14' '2016-01-17' '2016-01-24']"
```

list of print strings:

```
In [574]: [str(d) for d in np.hstack(alist).astype('datetime64[D]')]                                      
Out[574]: ['2016-01-04', '2016-01-14', '2016-01-17', '2016-01-24']
```

date strings without conversion:

```
In [575]: [str(d) for d in alist]                                                                         
Out[575]: 
['2016-01-04T00:00:00.000000000',
 '2016-01-14T00:00:00.000000000',
 '2016-01-17T00:00:00.000000000',
 '2016-01-24T00:00:00.000000000']
```